# Optimized search using Lookup and Search

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization, search-engine

I have a problem to solve, which looks to be quite challenging to me, but I am unable to find how to approach this problem. I have tried googling, but didn't found any concrete direction to proceed.

I am looking for some pointers, ideas, relevant material(s), name of some algorithms etc.

## Problem

Build a list of book titles. E.g. Given a text "If I may, I will laugh and live, like prince charm"
A possible list of books would be

- **If I may**
- **I will Laugh**, *tonight*
- **Laugh and Live** *in Timbackto*
- **Like Prince Charm**

It is desired to have a short list like the above rather than a long list like.

- **If** *I die*
- **I may** *die tonight*
- **I will** *be born again*
- **Laugh and** *cry*
- **Live** *Like a king*
- **Prince** *Helen in trouble*
- *The* **charm** *of living on mountain*
- ...

#### What is available

Available is an API for the library which provides a lookup and search service. Lookup performs specific searches given the title of the book where as the search provides a list of books given keyword(s).

#### Some additional constrains

- What can we do to make the result as short as possible? Can we find an optimal solution?
- How can we minimize the unmatched words?
- How can we use local cashing to improve the search for frequent sentences?

Thanks

Comment: I assume this is some theoretical exercise as opposed to a practical problem. If so, I don't really understand the purpose of the API functions - If lookup finds a book that matches an entire given book title, when would you ever want to use it? If it matches partial titles, how is it different from search?

Comment: It is practical as well. The lookup does not make sense, probably I shouldn't have mentioned that, but the search api available is not mature enough to search smartly, like breaking the given text smartly and doing the search using them.

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution could be the following :

For each word in your search, search for all the matching book names.

Then for each candidate, compute a correlation score between the tokenized book title and all the words in your search.

A basic correlation function could be something like :

```
public double correlation(String[] a, String[] b, int offset)
{
  double ret = 0.;
  int maxI = Math.min(a.length, b.length - offset);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < maxI ; i++)
  {
    ret += a[i].equals(b[i+offset]) / maxI;
  }
}
```

The offset parameter is used in order to be shift robust.

Then you can sort your book titles with this score.

Cheers